# How can I control multiple input-text in form in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

How can I control multiple input-text in form (in my case are 6 inputs). I've to get just one input to show hide button with JQuery and JS.

```
$("#multiLogin-search input.text-input")
```

thnx

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/#selecting-elements-with-a-comma-separated-list-of-selectors

Comment: Use DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()` and `find()`, to target the `input` related to the button. If you require a specific example of how to do that please add your own HTML and JS to the question

Comment: Please include enough information to provide a useful solution.  Do you have one control that needs to affect multiple others?  Do they all have the same class?

Comment: Perhaps some clarity in the question?  it looks like some of us are assuming you're asking how to select multiple inputs - but the line *get just one input* implies you already are selecting all, but **want just one**.   How do you identify the one that you want?  Where's your show/hide button in relation to the input(s).   Please include relevant HTML.  See [mcve].

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/petvuq9m/1/ I've do the control in input field. When i put input, i'll get my button search. Now i want to hide my button when input ==null. Can i find a help?

Answer (score 0):

You can comma seperate the selectors:

```
$("#multiLogin-search input.text-input, #second-input, #third-input")
```

Update:

If all your inputs have the same class, just use the following to select them all.

```
$(".text-input")
```

Comment: I've 6 inputs. They have the same class=text-input.

Comment: @Ayal maybe include that information in your question?

Comment: @AyaI I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I want to use true and false to do the control for my $(".text-input"), if i've input, removeclass (d-none) and addClass "buttonSearch"

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/petvuq9m/1/ I've do the control in input field. When i put input, i'll get my button search. Now i want to hide my button when input ==null. Can i find a help?